# Android OOM with Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-custom-view

So I'm seeing in Crashlytics we have quite a few crashes being caused by OOM with bitmaps.
Seems 60% of them come from Galaxy S7 Edge devices on 6.0.1.
What we have is a landing screen with 2 images, a background image that is being scrolled from right to left and then being recreated to give them impression of movement to the foreground image.

At the top of the Fabric log it says theres an error inflating the class.
However down further in the stack, I see it seems to get caused from our ParallaxImageView.
In here we do this:

```
private void initializeCustomAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ParallaxImageView,
            0, 0);

    try {
        speed = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_speed, 10);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.ParallaxImageView_src, 0));

    } finally {
        attributes.recycle();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is right where it happens or if one of the other methods could lead to this.
We also have these methods:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (canvas == null || bitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.getClipBounds(clipBounds);

    while (offset <= -bitmap.getWidth()) {
        offset += bitmap.getWidth();
    }

    float left = offset;
    while (left < clipBounds.width()) {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, getBitmapLeft(width, left), 0, null);
        left += width;
    }

    if (isAnimating && speed != 0) {
        offset -= abs(speed);
        postInvalidateOnAnimation();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    start();
}

@Override
public void start() {
    if (!isAnimating) {
        isAnimating = true;
        postInvalidateOnAnimation();
    }
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    if (isAnimating) {
        isAnimating = false;
        invalidate();
    }
}

 private Bitmap scaleToFitHeight(Bitmap bitmap, int height) {
    if (height > 0) {
        float factor = height / (float) bitmap.getHeight();

        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * factor), height, true);
        if (!newBitmap.equals(bitmap)) {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }

        return newBitmap;
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private float getBitmapLeft(float layerWidth, float left) {
    if (speed < 0) {
        return clipBounds.width() - layerWidth - left;
    } else {
        return left;
    }
}
```

I have no idea what could be causing this issue as I think we are decoding and recycling correctly. Not sure if it could be something specifically on 6.0.1 that is causing it, but any help here would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the logs too?

Answer (score 0):

you're not decoding the image correctly, you should first check the size and then decoding it with a scale factor. let's say your image is 2000 x 2000, the compressed version might easily be < 1mb but decompressing it into a bitmap would need 2000 * 2000 * 4 bytes = 16mb (!)
it might not be the case if you are sure that the image size is manageable but since you're getting OOM I guess it's not
see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) for implementation details